# javascript variable assign in function

Tags: variables, assign

i have a problem with a variable that i'm trying to assign, here is my partial code:

```
function calendar2(result1){
    //alert(result1);
    var calendar = $('#event_calendar');
    calendar.empty();
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay today prev,next'
        },

        //defaultView: 'basicWeek',

        editable: false,
        firstDay: 0,
        height: 600,
        droppable: false,
        events: result1,
```

...

if i uncomment 'alert(result1);' the result is shown but the text from **result1** is not assign to **events**. How can i assign it?
Waiting for a solution, thanks.

Comment: How do you know if the assignment worked or not ? Does the rest of the function do what it is supposed to do in both cases ?

Comment: if a put the text resulted from the variable result1, the function works...

Comment: the line is like this: events: [{},{},] and the result1 is a string containing the text [{},{},] should this be converted to array before events: result1 ?

Comment: Is events just empty or do you get javascript errors in the console when `alert()` is enabled ?

Comment: if i use events: [{title:...},] i get no errors in console log but if i use events: result1 and result1 is [{title:...},] i get error GET http://site/[%7Btitle%20%20%20:... 404 (Not Found) . i've tried setting up another var temp=600; and then height:temp, and it works so it must be something with that text?

Comment: You should update your question to show the value of `results1` received by `calendar2()`.

Comment: i didn't understand what you just said, the value of result1 is received correctly in calendar2(), if i copy the value of it and replace it in events: result1 with that text, the function works normally... any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously something is diffferent and being able to see the content of `result1` might help. Also, is result1 used elsewhere in the function or in the script ?

Comment: i've removed the var received and declared it normally inside the function: `var temp1='[{title : "413/96535115",start : new Date(2015,7,01),end : new Date(2015,7,01),allDay: true,id: "413",color: "#252A32"},{title : "414/the kooples",start : new Date(2015,7,04,01,00),end : new Date(2015,7,13,03,00),allDay: false,id: "414",color: "#FDA330"},]';` and then set `events: temp1,` and it doesn't work like i said before but if i put the string from temp1 in events like this `events: [{title : "413/96535115",start :..color: "#FDA330"},],` it works so?

Comment: How is the function called ? Is it a callback on an event ?

Comment: Hmm, `temp1` is a string representing an `array` while you assign an actual `array` to `events` directly. You might be feeding the wrong type to `events`.

Comment: yes i've said that from the start, how can i convert that string to array?

Comment: Why is it a string in the first place ? What is the source of `result1` ?

Comment: i used a $.post php code and the result used it with calendar2(data) so it's a string.

Comment: So it's presumably JSON. Try `events: JSON.parse(result1),`.

Comment: i've tried json.parse() before but didn't work because it was a string. i fixed the problem creating array in array with the php code and then json.parse() worked. thanks for the help:)

Comment: Glad it works. You can probably delete this question since in its current form it is not detailed enough to be helpful to other people.